# How can I make listed images fill all div width (not centering)

Tags: css

I'm trying to make listed images fill all div width without leaving any space on left and right (equal distribuition).

Something like this:

[image]

I tried using display.. but it doesn't work:

```css
#myDiv {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.myList li {
  display: table-cell;
  width:20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="listaCaptcha-wrap">
  <ul id="listaCaptcha-lista">
      <li><img src="01.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="02.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="03.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="04.jpg"></li>
      <li><img src="05.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with **Flexbox** and [`justify-content: space-between;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

> Flex items are evenly distributed along the line. The spacing is done such as the space between two adjacent items is the same. Main-start edge and main-end edge are flushed with respectively first and last flex item edges.

```css
ul {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also How does accepting an answer work?

Comment: I have to wait 2 minutes to choose the answer! I'll do it as soon as possible! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think this is best you could do with `display: table;` https://jsfiddle.net/L96586ju/